# "backwards" np.geomspace so a higher density occurs as log function gets higher

Tags: python, numpy, geometry, computational-geometry, logarithm

I need to generate numbers in a logarithmic space from .5 to 1.

This code accomplishes that:

`IN: np.geomspace(.5, 1, num=10)
OUT: [0.5, 0.540029869446153, 0.5832645197880583, 0.6299605249474366, 0.6803950000871885, 0.7348672461377994, 0.7937005259840997, 0.8572439828530728, 0.9258747122872905, 1.0]`

However, the smaller increments occur closer to .5. I'd like them to occur closer to 1 (hence, backwards, I'm just not entirely sure what the right term would be).

I've tried `np.geomspace(1, .5, num=10)` but it just gives me the same output in reverse order.

Comment: By definition, you are getting what yo mean by equally spaced in logarithmic space. Do you mean you want to map equally spaced linear points mapped to interval 0.5 and 1 in logarithmic scale?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

IIUC you can do:

```py
import numpy as np

1.5 - np.geomspace(1, .5, num=10)
array([0.5       , 0.57412529, 0.64275602, 0.70629947, 0.76513275,
       0.819605  , 0.87003948, 0.91673548, 0.95997013, 1.        ])
```